# Не срабатывает скрипт

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите пожалуйста , есть карточки на сайте в слайдере . В CodePen все работает как надо "codepen.io/ewgen-tewilin/pen/VgKmvQ" , а вот на сайте а разделе материалы не хочет срабатывать test.cowboy.beget.tech . Менял и расположение скрипта и удалял все скрипты кроме этого и все равно не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Исходная [ссылка](http://codepen.io/ewgen-tewilin/pen/VgKmvQ)

Перенесенный оттуда код прекрасно работает. Надо было только подключить jquery:

```js
var $card = $('.material_card');
var lastCard = $(".material_card-list .material_card").length - 1;

$('.material_next').click(function(){ 
 var prependList = function() {
  if( $('.material_card').hasClass('activeNow') ) {
   var $slicedCard = $('.material_card').slice(lastCard).removeClass('transformThis activeNow');
   $('ul').prepend($slicedCard);
  }
 }
 $('li').last().removeClass('transformPrev').addClass('transformThis').prev().addClass('activeNow');
 setTimeout(function(){prependList(); }, 150);
});

$('.material_prev').click(function() {
 var appendToList = function() {
  if( $('.material_card').hasClass('activeNow') ) {
   var $slicedCard = $('.material_card').slice(0,1).addClass('transformPrev');
   $('.material_card-list').append($slicedCard);
  }}
 
   $('li').removeClass('transformPrev').last().addClass('activeNow').prevAll().removeClass('activeNow');
 setTimeout(function(){appendToList();}, 150);
});
```

```css
.material_card-stack {
  width: 700px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.material_card-stack .material_buttons {
/*   display: none; */
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 0;
  top: 55%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
/* .card-stack .buttons:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
} */
.material_card-stack .material_prev {
  left: 15px;
  right: auto;
}
.material_card-stack .material_next {
  left: auto;
  right: 15px;
}
.material_card-stack .carousel .material_buttons:hover {
  color: #C01313 ;
  background: #fff;
}
.material_card-stack .material_card-list {
  width: 300px;
}
.material_card-stack .material_card-list li {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.material_card-stack .material_card-list li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 24px;
  width: 60%;
  /* animation: scaleCard 100ms; */

}
.material_card-stack .material_card-list li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 36px;
  width: 70%;
}
.material_card-stack .material_card-list li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 48px;
  width: 80%;
}
.material_card-stack .material_card-list li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 60px;
  width: 90%;
}
.material_card-stack .material_card-list li:nth-child(5) {
  top: 72px;
  width: 100%;
}
.material_card-stack:hover > .material_buttons.material_prev {
  display: block;
  animation: bounceInLeft 200ms;
}
.material_card-stack:hover > .material_buttons.material_next {
  display: block;
  animation: bounceInRight 200ms;
}
.transformThis {
  animation: scaleDown 500ms;
}
.transformPrev {
  animation: scaleUp 100ms;
}
@keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0.10;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(30px);
    opacity: 0.20;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.05) translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0.40;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.01) translateY(10px);
    opacity: 0.80;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleDown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.01) translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0.80;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.05) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0.40;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(60px);
    opacity: 0.20;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(80px);
    opacity: 0.10;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleCard {
  0% {
    top: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 24px;
  }
/* }
 @keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
} 
@keyframes bounceInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-40px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}  */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="material_card-stack">
    <a class="material_buttons material_prev" href="#"><</a>
    <ul class="material_card-list">
     <li class="material_card" style="background-color: #FF3B30;"></li>
     <li class="material_card" style="background-color: #34AADC;"></li>   
     <li class="material_card" style="background-color: #FF9500;"></li>
   </ul> 
   <a class="material_buttons material_next" href="#">></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: На самом деле вчера вечером решил вопрос , дело было не в jquery , его подключал даже старой версией , для теста. Проблема была в том , что надо было в обработчик добавить preventdefault, сразу перестало кидать вверх страницы ))

Comment: в jquery-обработчиках достаточно делать return false, он сам preventdefault вставит. а так да, согласен, при клике на ссылку надо отменять действие по-умолчанию (переход по href).